# Implementation of comment system (Facebook like)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I am looking for a way to create comment system that behaves like Facebook's post comment section.

Right now I have this structure:

[image: Structure]

But I need to implement also replies to comments and replies to replies and so on.
What should be done to achieve the behavior same to Facebook's?

Comment: If it helped, you need to accept answer, to let other find it faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement swipe to `reply` or `delete` and other things, use this library:
[MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell)

For reply and delete do like this:

```
private func addFuncButtons(to cell: CommentCell, at row: Int) {
  let currentUserId = User.getCurrentUserId()

  if (cell.comment.userId == currentUserId // if its current user comment
     || userId! == currentUserId) // if current user is post author
     && cell.comment.key != "" { // cant delete desc
     cell.rightButtons = [
        MGSwipeButton(title: "", icon: UIImage(named:"delete.png"), backgroundColor: .red) {
           (sender: MGSwipeTableCell!) -> Bool in
           self.removeCell(cell, at: row)
           return true
        },
        MGSwipeButton(title: "", icon: UIImage(named:"reply.png"), backgroundColor: .darkGray) {
           (sender: MGSwipeTableCell!) -> Bool in
           self.replyToUser(with: cell.userNickName.currentTitle!)
           return true
        }
     ]
  } else {
     // add only reply button
     cell.rightButtons = [
        MGSwipeButton(title: "", icon: UIImage(named:"reply.png"), backgroundColor: .darkGray) {
           (sender: MGSwipeTableCell!) -> Bool in
           self.replyToUser(with: cell.userNickName.currentTitle!)
           return true
        }
     ]
  }

  cell.rightSwipeSettings.transition = .rotate3D
}
```

Actions:

```
private func removeCell(_ cell: CommentCell, at row: Int) {
  removeCellFromTable(cell, at: row)
  removeCellFromDataBase(cell)
}

private func removeCellFromTable(_ cell: CommentCell, at row: Int) {
   comments.remove(at: row)
   tableView.reloadData()
}

private func removeCellFromDataBase(_ cell: CommentCell) {
   Comment.remove(cell.comment, from: post)
}

private func replyToUser(with login: String) {
   newCommentTextField.text = newCommentTextField.text?.appending(" @" + login)
}
```

Like that.

Hope it helps